# What is joining table on some selected columns technically called?

Tags: sql

```
Select t1.column1,t1.column2,t2.column1,t2.column2 from table1 t1 
join (select column1,min(column2) from table2 group by column1) t2
On table1.column1 = table2.column1
```

Joining tables on some select column from other table rather than the whole table.

> What is it technically called? Is it called a sub query?

Comment: I've always just called it a subquery [inner | outer | etc..] join, since that's exactly what it is, I'm not aware of a conceptual name outside of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a subquery.

This could also be written as:

```
Select t1.column1,
    t1.column2,
    t2.column1 
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2
    On t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

Since you are only using the subquery to return one column and you are not using an aggregate or some other operation, I would not use a subquery in that situation.  If you want to use an aggregate function, then sometimes it is easier to use a subquery due to the use of `group by`:

```
Select t1.column1,
    t1.column2,
    t2.column1 
from table1 t1 
join
(
    select column1, MAX(date) MaxDate
    from table2
    group by column1
) t2
    On t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

Comment: I think i have written it more simply. But i just wanted to know the name. I want to add (select customer_nme from customer group by customer_nme) t2

Comment: @Abhishekkumar there are times that a subquery is helpful, especially when applying aggregates and group by.  see my edit

Comment: you do have to be careful with subqueries though, because they can impact performance in ways that aren't always obvious.

Comment: @bluefeet-the inner query can be termed sub query but is this join termed simple join or it has some other technical name?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar It is just a join. To be precise I am using an `INNER JOIN` on the table and the subquery

Answer (score 1):

What you're essentially doing is joining on an anonymous view.  Imagine instead you did:

```
create view t2 as select column1 from table2

select t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column1 from table1 t1 join t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column2
```

That's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an "inner equi-join", because the join condition is an equality.  I'm not sure what you mean by "some select column from other table rather than the whole table".  Joins normally use only one or two columns between tables.  The columns are typically either primary keys or foreign keys.

This query is simply getting the smallest value `table2.column2` for each value of `table1.column1` *and* filtering out any values of `table1.column1` that are not in `table2`.  There isn't really a special phrase for exactly this type of join.